# StackLevelTooDeep in Rails 4.0.12 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When booting Rails 4 application (migrated from Rails 3) everything works correctly - however when trying to access main website I've got `StackLevelTooDeep` exception.

How to debug this (stacktrace points at `reloader.rb`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was one of the scopes in model - in Rails 4.0.12 if you have scope called `all` you **will** get `StackLevelTooDeep` exceptions when trying to access that model from controller.

However when updated to Rails 4.1 it gave message about wrong scope name: `all`. So that was the way I debugged this.